# React Native with typescript unable to resolve modules

Tags: typescript, react-native

This is embarrassing, but I don't know what else to do. I wanted to port my little React Native project to TypeScript, so I created an empty React Native project with TypeScript template, tweaked `tsconfig.json` to use custom paths such as `@app` and I tried to run it. It didn't. And this was yesterday, I did some googling, but those who had the same issue suggested to clean the packager, remove `node_modules` and reinstall packages all over, for example, [this one](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24509), so I did, and it didn't work.

These are my steps for reinstalling `react-native-cli` (at first I thought that the problem is with outdated package, it wasn't):

- `npm uninstall -g react-native-cli`
- `yarn global add @react-native-community/cli`

Those below I followed already that many times, that I don't remember the exact number:

- `npx react-native init MyApp --template react-native-template-typescript`
- `yarn add redux redux-logger redux-thunk react-redux`
- `yarn add --dev @types/react @types/react-redux @types/redux-logger`

And then making changes to `tsconfig.json`, so it looks likes this ( my changes marked with `->`):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    /* Basic Options */
    "target": "esnext",                       /* Specify ECMAScript target version: 'ES3' (default), 'ES5', 'ES2015', 'ES2016', 'ES2017','ES2018' or 'ESNEXT'. */
    "module": "esnext",                       /* Specify module code generation: 'none', 'commonjs', 'amd', 'system', 'umd', 'es2015', or 'ESNext'. */
    "lib": ["dom", "esnext"],                 /* Specify library files to be included in the compilation. */
    "allowJs": true,                          /* Allow javascript files to be compiled. */
    "jsx": "react-native",                    /* Specify JSX code generation: 'preserve', 'react-native', or 'react'. */
    "noEmit": true,                           /* Do not emit outputs. */
    "incremental": true,                      /* Enable incremental compilation */
    "isolatedModules": true,                  /* Transpile each file as a separate module (similar to 'ts.transpileModule'). */

    /* Strict Type-Checking Options */
    "strict": true,                           /* Enable all strict type-checking options. */

    /* Module Resolution Options */
    "moduleResolution": "node",               /* Specify module resolution strategy: 'node' (Node.js) or 'classic' (TypeScript pre-1.6). */
->  "baseUrl": "./src",                       /* Base directory to resolve non-absolute module names. */
->  "paths": {                                /* A series of entries which re-map imports to lookup locations relative to the 'baseUrl'. */
->    "@app/*": ["./*"]
->  },
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,     /* Allow default imports from modules with no default export. This does not affect code emit, just typechecking. */
    "esModuleInterop": true                   /* Enables emit interoperability between CommonJS and ES Modules via creation of namespace objects for all imports. Implies 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports'. */    
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules", "babel.config.js", "metro.config.js", "jest.config.js"
  ]
}
```

My project structure looks like this:

```
MyApp
├── ios
├── android
├── src
│   ├── index.tsx
│   ├── constants
│   │   └── app.json
│   ├── support   
│   │   └── store.tsx   
│   └── reducers   
│       └── index.tsx
├── tsconfig.json
├── package.json
├── index.js 
└── [ the rest ]
```

And when I'm trying to `import {initStore} from '@app/support/store'` in `MyApp/src/index.tsx` the Metro gives me the following:

```
Loading dependency graph, done.
error: bundling failed: Error: Unable to resolve module `@app/support/store` from `src/index.tsx`: @app/support/store could not be found within the project.
```

Then I tried cleaning with following commands, but it also didn't do any good:

- `watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* && rm -rf node_modules/ && npm cache verify && npm install && npm start -- --reset-cache`

But, what interesting, after that I tweaked `tsconfig.json`, Atom doesn't complain about paths like `@app/support/store`, it even provides autocompletion, it recognizes `@app/support/` as directory and `@app/support/store` as a script, so I assume `tsconfig.json` is not the problem.

Comment: 1. I assume you restarted your packager? 2. Is that all of the error you get? 3. Does import work for anything else beside `support/store`, e.g. `@app/constants/app`?

Comment: @nabn No, the import doesn't work for any files with the absolute path. By packager you mean Metro? Then restarting it won't fix it, I tried, as well as clearing cache `yarn start --reset-cache`.

Answer (score 7):

Seems the problem was with babel configuration. You would need to run

`yarn add --dev babel-plugin-module-resolver`

to install module-resolver and then adjust `babel.config.js` so it would look like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    [
      'module-resolver',
      {
        root: ['./src'],
        alias: {
          '^@app/(.+)': './src/\\1',
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
}
```

Comment: That helped, thanks! Make sure you delete the watchman cache after adding the module resolver to the babel config.

Comment: @Katherine the package name should be `babel-plugin-module-resolver`

Comment: Setting alias to simply `{ '@app': './src/app' }` also worked for me.